# Is there a reverse-searchable dictionary?

Tags: webapp-rec

I use [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/) and [Wiktionary](http://www.wiktionary.org/). I'm looking for a way to search within definitions and do other searches on either of those sites or a site where these kinds of searches can be performed.

- search for all words that contain a word or phrase *in their definition*
- search for all words that match a pattern: eg. `un*ly` or `*just*`
- not essential: search on parts of speech or etymology
- Boolean combinations

I once had some desktop software that would do this. I know the patterns can be searched in scrabble dictionaries, but they don't often have full-text definitions.

Comment: Really? _Six and a half years_ after the question was asked and answered it's been put on hold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is called [OneLook](http://www.onelook.com/?w=un%2aly&ls=b&sourceid=Mozilla-search).

Answer (score 1):

For searching by pattern, I use the [Regex Dictionary](http://www.visca.com/regexdict/), it's very useful. You can't search in their definition though, but it does your second point really well.

Comment: It also does my third (and fourth) point(s).